# React.js: Use Map function to Array of Objects into Array of Array depends by specified attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to reformat my data to it can fit into `React-Google-Chart` 's data format.

My data current(which is saved as state) is array of objects. like following:

```
[ { _id: 5bbbb89a1a3ab50bcbd750a3,
    desc: 'Market',
    total: 4000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:05:45  PM' },
  { _id: 5bbbb8ac1a3ab50bcbd750a7,
    desc: 'Deliver',
    total: 2000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:06:03  PM' },
  { _id: 5bbbb8ac1a3ab50bcbd750a8,
    desc: 'Market',
    total: 4000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:06:03  PM' },
  { _id: 5bbbb8ac1a3ab50bcbd750a9,
    desc: 'CPM',
    total: 14000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:06:03  PM' },
  { _id: 5bbca335ef3899eb5fcbed51,
    desc: 'Deliver',
    total: 4000,
    amount: 2,
    timestamp: '10/9/2018  8:46:44  AM' }]
```

I am trying to map them into the following:

```
[["Market", "2"], ["Deliver", 3], ["CPM", 1"]]
```

What I have so far worked, but did not work in the way I wanted.
Let me explain: this piece of data gets send from the backed and it was saved as a state in `componentDidMount()`. And my function that convey the data format will be called in the initial render. So here is the problem, without using map function, this function will fail because during the initial render, there is no data in my state. One way I found is to use map function so i will worked for my initial render.

what I have so far:

```
mapBarArray(){
    if(this.state.history.length > 0){
        var barObject =[]
        for(var eachItem of this.state.history){
            var desc = eachItem.desc;
            var amount = eachItem.amount;
            if (!barObject[desc]) {
                barObject[desc] = [
                    desc,
                    amount
                ];
              }else{
                barObject[desc][1] +=1
              }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will return array of object of array. Then I can push value of each object into my final array, which gets what I want. However, this method does not use map, so it will  fail the initial render.

`What I need help with`: Use map function or any sort of function so it will be convey during initial render so i can use it to map the charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as simple as `data.map (({amount, desc}) => [desc, amount])`

Edit, i didn't realize you're aggregating the amount. In that case I usually do something along the lines of:

```
 map = data.reduce ((map, {amount, desc}) =>  {
   map [desc] = ~~map[desc] + ~~amount;
   return map;
},{});

Object.keys (map).map (k => [k,map[k]]);
```

```js
let map = data.reduce ((map, {amount, desc}) =>  {
   map [desc] = ~~map[desc] + ~~amount;
   return map;
},{});
let mapped = Object.keys (map).map (k => [k,map[k]]);
console.log (JSON.stringify(mapped))
```

```html
<script> 
var data = [ { _id: "5bbbb89a1a3ab50bcbd750a3",
    desc: 'Market',
    total: 4000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:05:45  PM' },
  { _id: "5bbbb8ac1a3ab50bcbd750a7",
    desc: 'Deliver',
    total: 2000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:06:03  PM' },
  { _id: "5bbbb8ac1a3ab50bcbd750a8",
    desc: 'Market',
    total: 4000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:06:03  PM' },
  { _id: "5bbbb8ac1a3ab50bcbd750a9",
    desc: 'CPM',
    total: 14000,
    amount: 1,
    timestamp: '10/8/2018  4:06:03  PM' },
  { _id: "5bbca335ef3899eb5fcbed51",
    desc: 'Deliver',
    total: 4000,
    amount: 2,
    timestamp: '10/9/2018  8:46:44  AM' }]
</script>
```

Comment: @what doe `~~` do in this case

Comment: `~` is a binary negation. I use it two times to convert `map[desc]`  to a number (which is  intitally`undefined` ). The second `~~` is only needed if your `amount` may contain `undefined` or `NaN`